# exec() for importing sql file

Tags: php

how can i use exec() method to import a .sql file in php?
what is its output?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you mean by import a .sql file?  Are you trying to run a pre-written sql query on a database?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the command line client. For example, using mysql:

```
  exec('mysql db_name < script.sql > results')
```