# run mysql.sql using php

Tags: php, mysql

i have mysql file. it has .sql extension. how to run  that "mysql" file using php script? how is the script should be?
the mysql file is already on the server, and i want to run this query using php file which is placed on the same place with mysql file...

Comment: you could use exec like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464571/exec-for-importing-sql-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this

```
$query=file_get_contents($file);

$mysqli->multi_query($query);
```

[mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) can do the job.

Comment: as written in this doc :  Executes one or multiple queries which are concatenated by a semicolon.

Comment: @gaurav: you are right But it will take care of value which contains `;`

Answer (score 0):

> the mysql file is already on the server

dun use PHP ....

Linux ???

install mysql client, and run a shell like

```
mysql -u root -ppassword -P port_number < any.sql
```

Windows ???

still need to install mysql client, repeat from above

---

**if you don't have ssh access to the server, and don't have exec right**

read/prepare again the mysql file by breaking multiple queries then execute one-by-one